# Check length of list in list comprehension (Iteration based on the count of elements within list comprehension)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I need to calculate just first five prime numbers. I want to check the length of list while building it in list comprehension. The following code doesn't work.

```
def checkPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True



 primes = [] 
 primes = [x  for x in range(2,30) if(checkPrime(x) and len(primes)<6) ] 
 print primes
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

Why `len(primes)<6` is not working here. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your new `primes` is just being created. You are checking the length of an empty list all the time.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I check the length or maintain a counter in the list comprehension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Pythonic" way is to use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), plus the [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function:

```
from itertools import islice

def checkPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

def primes():
    i = 2
    while True:
        if checkPrime(i):
            yield i
        i += 1

first_5 = list(islice(primes, 5))
```

What this will do is create an infinite "list" called `primes` that you can use in many ways that a list can be used, but it will only actually calculate the values that you need.

Comment: It throws an error saying object function is not an iterable

Comment: You may need to do `list(first_5)`. I'll update the sample so it just automatically makes it a list.

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools.islice` combined with `filter` to make your computation lazy.

```
from itertools import islice

def checkPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

primes = filter(checkPrime, range(2, 10**100))

list(islice(primes, 6))  # [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```

Answer (score 3):

***List Comprehension* creates and returns the new list.** In your code, within the *list comprehension*, `len(primes)` will always return zero because the length of list will not be updated till the list comprehension is complete and new list is returned.

**If it is must for you to use a *list comprehension***, you may create a *generator* function to return you the next prime in the range. Within the list comprehension call the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the generator object (using the `range` to restrict the count of required values).

For example:

```
def checkPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

# Generator function
def getPrimes(n):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if(checkPrime(x)):
            yield x

# Create Generator object
primes_gen = getPrimes(30)

# List comprehension to get primes
primes = [next(primes_gen) for _ in range(5)]
#         ^                               ^ required count of prime numbers in list
#         ^ to get next prime number
```

The final value hold by `primes` will be:

```
>>> primes
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

As suggested in [*robbrit's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49114459/2063361), **Pythonic way to achieve this is using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)** *(but it is not a list comprehension as you requested)*:

```
>>> from itertools import islice

#    v type-casting it to list for displaying the list, 
#    v   as `islice` also returns a generator object
>>> list(islice(getPrimes(30), 5))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]  # ^ generator function from my older example
```

Answer (score 0):

The top voted answer is good, but `itertools.count` makes it even better. It's like a `range` without un upper limit.

```py
from itertools import islice, count

def checkPrime(n):
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

first_5 = list(islice(filter(checkPrime, count(2)), 5))
```

Out of scope, but if you wanted to be even more Pythonic, use `any` instead of a separate helper function:

```py
from itertools import islice, count

first_5 = list(islice(filter(lambda n: not any(n % k == 0 for k in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1)), count(2)), 5))
```

A little messy, but you could always use `any` inside `checkPrime`:

```py
def checkPrime(n):
    return not any(n % k == 0 for k in range(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1))
```